# Loading Different HTML Pages in a Main HTML Page using HTML5 Websockts

Tags: html, websocket

i have a situation where i want to load different webpages in a browser where the URL will be passed over the web-sockets.
Now the problem is, if inside one html page which is connected to the sockets server, it receives a command to redirect to another url, the socket connection is lost and it is not possible for the new page unless it has this socket functionality built in it.
One idea is to use a main page with inlineFrame where i keep changing the pages while main page remains connected to the socket server.
I want to know, is there more efficient way of doing this task where i am supposed to received url commands over the socket but idea is to avoid iFrames??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your main page is acting like a web browser. It gets a new URL and then loads a real page based on that. You need something to maintain state and control which page is loading and the only way to maintain state with WebSockets is to keep that page open and the connection established.

The only solution I can see is the IFRAME one that you have suggested.

Comment: thanks, the only problem with iFrame is the cursor. I have a custom made cursor which would be used in a large screen output, and i don't have access to iFrame code to embed cursor code in there. If i add a transpared div layer, then i can't click elements inside Iframe. Seems like there's no way to solve this problem.

Comment: Since you don't 'own' the contents of the IFRAME I think you are right in saying that there's no solution to your cursor problem/requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Great question! 
I was thinking about this too. 
To fix all the links do something on the server or client side
Loop this (code is sketchy, but its the right idea):
DOMObj = Your Data Object with page content

```
i=0
linkArray[i] = DOMObj.getElementsByTag('a').firstChild[i]
DOMObj.getElementsByTag('a').firstChild[i].href = "href='serverLoad(linkArray[i])'"
```